# The best (or the proper) way to reuse action at any route? [Laravel 4.2]

Tags: php, laravel, view, laravel-4, controller

I'm just learning some `Laravel 4.2` with a book I got recently (mainly the reason I learn `4.2` first, not `5`). But now I'm kinda unsure.

Let's say I have a Blog application. There will always be a sidebar with list of categories (all in DB). What is the best way to get all categories and always show them no matter what route/controller am I in?

1. In `View` should I simply call model `Categories::all()` and work on it? What if I want more business logic (let's say in future don't show categories empty, only categories current user can access etc.)
2. Should I make controller for retrieving categories and pass it back, and call that controller everytime with `App::make('CategoryController')->getList()`?
3. Other way I'm not aware of?

I look for a way to have some code to run everytime, shared to many controllers (for example if user is logged in, then another box shows in sidebar with some info).

So far I think that approach **#1** is the one I should use.

But I want to confirm if it is. Or if there is the *proper* way to do it I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using V4.2 , which has something called [View Composer](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#view-composers)

Check out [this](http://culttt.com/2014/02/10/using-view-composers-laravel-4/) tutorial. This will solve your problem I think.